# Is there any way to check which of part is expanding most after installation?

Tags: android, google-play, size, apk

My 3MB App(used proguard to reduce size) on Play-store 
but after installation, it becomes 22MB. 
I want to reduce this 22MB size on phone to somewhere 8 to 10MB

Anybody know any tool which will tell who is taking most size after installation?? so that I can reduce that part of the app or remove that features from the app.

below is highligted part for which i want to see distribution 

[image]

on @Ankita request

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

signingConfigs {
    release_config {
        keyAlias 'XXXX'
        keyPassword 'XXXX'
        storeFile file('F:\\key.jks')

        storePassword 'XXXX'
    }
}

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "in.workindia.nileshdungarwal.workindiaandroid"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22

    versionCode 138
    versionName "3.9.3.1"

    resConfigs "en", "hi"
    //testApplicationId 'in.workindia.nileshdungarwal.workindiaandroid.test'
}

buildTypes {
    release {

        //versionNameSuffix "-DEV-TEST"
        //applicationIdSuffix ".test"
        debuggable false
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release_config
    }

    debug {
        useProguard false
        versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"

        /*Disable the fabric for debug version and do not update*/
        ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
    }

}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    jumboMode true
}

buildTypes.debug {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URLS', DEBUG_URLS

    it.buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'BRANCH_IO_MODE_IS_LIVE', BRANCH_IO_MODE_DEBUG

    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OFFICE_CONTACT_NO', OFFICE_CONTACT_NO

    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'CLIENT_ID', SERVER_DEBUG_CLIENT_ID
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'SECRET_KEYS', SERVER_DEBUG_CLIENT_SECRET

    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'GOOGLE_GEOLOCATION_API_KEY', GOOGLE_DEBUG_GEOLOCATION_API_KEY
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'TAG_MANAGER_CONTANER_ID', DEBUG_TAG_MANAGER_CONTANER_ID

    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'MQTT_BROKER_USERNAME', MQTT_BROKER_USERNAME
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'MQTT_BROKER_PASSWORD', MQTT_BROKER_PASSWORD

    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'POLE_API_KEY', POLE_API_KEY
}

buildTypes.release {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URLS', BASE_URLS

    it.buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'BRANCH_IO_MODE_IS_LIVE', BRANCH_IO_MODE_LIVE

    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OFFICE_CONTACT_NO', OFFICE_CONTACT_NO

    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'CLIENT_ID', SERVER_RELEASE_CLIENT_ID
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'SECRET_KEYS', SERVER_RELEASE_CLIENT_SECRET

    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'GOOGLE_GEOLOCATION_API_KEY', GOOGLE_RELEASE_GEOLOCATION_API_KEY
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'TAG_MANAGER_CONTANER_ID', RELEASE_TAG_MANAGER_CONTANER_ID

    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'MQTT_BROKER_USERNAME', MQTT_BROKER_USERNAME
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'MQTT_BROKER_PASSWORD', MQTT_BROKER_PASSWORD

    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'POLE_API_KEY', POLE_API_KEY
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
 }
            afterEvaluate {
           //    processDebugGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToDebug
               processReleaseGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToRelease
           }

           task printDependencies << {
               configurations.compile.each { println it.name }
           }

           task switchToDebug(type: Copy) {
               description = 'Switches to DEBUG google-services.json'
               from "src/debug_work"
               include "google-services.json"
               into "."
           }

           task switchToRelease(type: Copy) {
               description = 'Switches to RELEASE google-services.json'
               from "src/release_work"
               include "google-services.json"
               into "."
           }

           dependencies {
               compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
               compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
                   transitive = true;
               }
               compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1') {
                   exclude module: 'support-v4'
                   transitive = true
               }
               compile files('libs/GoogleConversionTrackingSdk-2.2.4.jar')
               compile 'me.pushy:sdk:1.0.26'
               compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+'
               compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.19.0'
               compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
               compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.6.1'
               compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'
               compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
               compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
               compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
               compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
               compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.3'
               compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.3'
               compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3'
               compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.+'
               compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
               compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.1.0'
               compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
               compile 'com.edmodo:rangebar:1.0.0'
               compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
           }

           apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: show your gradle file.

Comment: @Ankita proguard is properly applied, previously my app was 5MB now it is 3.3MB, so no problem with progaurd, but still if you want, definitely I can post

Comment: yes i want to see.

Comment: @Ankita gradle file is posted, but I am pretty sure, it will confuse people, they might think I am asking about playstore apk size. but my question is for after installation of app

Answer (score 1):

I would personally say that Use [**`ProGuard`**](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard)

> ProGuard will remove the unused Java code. It helps to significantly
>   reduce the code foot prints.ProGuard is the most popular optimizer for Java bytecode. It makes your Java and Android applications up to 90% smaller and up to 20% faster. ProGuard also provides minimal protection against reverse engineering by obfuscating the names of classes, fields and methods.

Read official guideline about [**`Reduce APK Size`**](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html) .

Comment: Really helpful link and tool it is.

Comment: @Ankita Yes, It is .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya My question is "Who is taking max size on phone after installation"?

Comment: @LokeshTiwari https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace.html

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I think systrace.html is more of while running app. I am trying to find which part of my app is expanding most after installation